# How to show "% of SubTotal" in Cross Tab in Pivot Table (Excel)

Tags: excel, pivot, dax

I have a table with sales by store, quarter and bike categories . How can I create a pivot table that shows the percentage per store, quarter and category, related to the subtotal of each store?

I want to answer the question: How is the percentage of bikes sales category and quarter for each store?"

[image: base table, pivot table with values, pivot tables wanted]

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this my creating a measure and add subtotals to the Power Pivot Layout.

**End Result:**

[image]

---

1. Create a table of the data:

[image]

2. Add the data to a model (Insert -> PivotTable -> "Add this data...")

[image]

3. Create a PivotTable and click on the table. Then create a new measure

[image]

4. Fill in the relevant information

We sum the sales and then divide it by the total store category

```
=DIVIDE(SUM(Table1[Sales]),CALCULATE(SUM([Sales]),ALLEXCEPT(Table1,Table1[Store])))
```

[image]

5. The table should now look like this:

[image]

using the following Fields Setup:

[image]

6. Let's add the subcategory numbers. Click on the PivotTable and then we choose to show all the subtotal at "Top of Group".

[image]

---

You can remove the "Grand Total" row by right click on the PivotTable and choose "PivotTable options.." and then untick "Show Grand Totals for columns..."

[image]

---

If we only want to have a measure for the "Sum Store by Quarter of Total Store percentage" (i.e. 75/312 = 24,04% in the row Store B), then we can use:

```
=DIVIDE(CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Sales]),ALLEXCEPT(Table1,Table1[Quarter],Table1[Store])),CALCULATE(SUM([Sales]),ALLEXCEPT(Table1,Table1[Store])))
```

Comment: @plehmann2005, Did you get the question solved :)?